# Receiving HTTP 401 Unauthorized when making a Google plus API call

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get the list of all my friends from the Google plus via API. The user on whose behalf I'm doing this operation previously authorized my request and I got the auth token. I've tried the following code in php:

```
function CallAPI() {
  $opts = array(
    "http" => array(
      "method" => "GET"
    )
  );

  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?key=XXXX';    
  $context = stream_context_create($opts);
  $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  var_dump($response);
}
```

but I keep receiving HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized. How can I prove that the user authorized my operations or what am I doing wrong?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to authenticate the user to use the special keyword "me" so using your simple API key will not work (assuming the key passed is your simple key). Instead, you need to get an access token and pass that.

For a great example of how to do this in PHP using the PHP client library, try the quickstart:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

---

If you are already getting an access token, you can call tokeninfo passing access token to get more information about who the user is associated with it:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.xxxxxxxx...

At this point, you could call:
'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/[useridfromaccesstoken]/people/visible?key=XXXX';

To verify that your API key is correct but I would recommend using the client library as demonstrated in the quickstart sample.